meaning, history "estoy en ello"
Does "estoy en ello" translate to English "I'm on it"?  That's a colloquial, informal expression in English. Is it also a colloquial, informal expression in Spanish?  Such a coincidence.  What's the history of this expression?
English and Spanish have a shared ancestry if you go back two thousand years. Is "estoy en ello" an example of that?  Or did Spanish pick up this expression from American movies in the last 20 years?  Or vice versa. Perhaps there will be no answers. But it is interesting.

"ello" is rather formal in Spanish. To make it informal, you should say "estoy en eso".

Alright.  Even if it's "estoy en eso".. is that correct (in Spanish)?  The point is, that in English, it's an idiom, an informal expression, somewhat unusual.

"Estoy en eso" is both correct and usual in Spanish to mean "I'm dealing with it".

In google ngram, comparing "I'm busy" with "I'm on it", the second one seems to appear suddenly, out of nowhere, 20-30 years ago.   It seems this expression exists in both Spanish and English.   What is the origin...  (not that it means "I'm busy", but that is for comparison of statistics, to compare to something common).

Sorry I cannot help with the origin. In DRAE (https://dle.rae.es/estar), the only meaning that seems to be close to it is: estar alguien en todo 1. loc. verb. Atender a un tiempo a muchas cosas, sin aturdirse por la mucha cantidad de ellas. If we replace "en todo" with "en eso", we have that "estar en eso" means "atender algo" (be busy with something).

@Gustavson In this context, for me "Estoy en ello" is more common that "Estoy en eso" and it's not formal.

@Sam if you compare the Ngram EN "I'm on it" vs the Ngram ES "Estoy en eso, estoy en ello", you can see that the Spanish version predates the English one. Also you can see that "Estoy en eso" was the first to appear and it's slightly more used than "Estoy en ello"

@Sam Also, I don't agree with your statement about the ancestry. French is not an ancestor of Spanish. French and Spanish both come from Latin. Spanish have some words taken from French.

@RubioRic maybe it could have been phrased differently.  There are a tremendous number of words the same between English and Spanish.  They can be traced back to "vulgar Latin", which would have been a mutually intelligible language between Spain and France if you go back far enough in time.

@Sam Sure. My point is that the three languages share Latin roots but not French roots.

@RubioRic In my dialect, "ello" is always formal, and we always use "eso" in everyday language instead.

@Gustavson wrote ""Estoy en eso" is both correct and usual in Spanish to mean "I'm dealing with it".   So, "I'm dealing with it".  Do you have any ideas about how long ago that was the meaning of the phrase?  To you, does this sound like modern slang, or do you guess people could have used this expression in the 1800s?

The oldest people around today in 2024, were alive in the 1940's. Could you ask one of them what their opinion is?  :-)))  "Is it new slang?" or "That is just normal Spanish, dating back to Cervantes".
